# Maven won't run Android instrumentation tests

Tags: java, android, maven, android-maven-plugin

How should Android instrumentation tests be run for automatic testing with jayway's maven-android-plugin?

I checked out [apidemos-android-16](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/apidemos-android-16) and ran them with `mvn clean install`, but only 7 unit tests were executed. `Focus2ActivityTest` for example didn't run. `mvn android:instrument` gives the same results.

The Maven output:

```
[INFO] Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] android.device parameter not set, using all attached devices
[INFO] Emulator emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk found.
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :   Successfully installed C:\dev\jayway-maven-android-plugin-samples\apidemos-android-16\instrumen
tationtests\target\instrumentationtests-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apk to emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.7.0:internal-integration-test (default-internal-integration-test) @ instrumentationtests ---
[INFO] Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] android.device parameter not set, using all attached devices
[INFO] Emulator emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk found.
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :   Running instrumentation tests in com.example.android.apis.tests
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :     Run started: com.example.android.apis.tests, 7 tests:
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       Start [1/7]: com.example.android.apis.ApiDemosApplicationTests#testPreconditions
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       End [1/7]: com.example.android.apis.ApiDemosApplicationTests#testPreconditions
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       Start [2/7]: com.example.android.apis.app.LocalServiceTest#testPreconditions
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       End [2/7]: com.example.android.apis.app.LocalServiceTest#testPreconditions
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       Start [3/7]: com.example.android.apis.app.LocalServiceTest#testStartable
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       End [3/7]: com.example.android.apis.app.LocalServiceTest#testStartable
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       Start [4/7]: com.example.android.apis.os.MorseCodeConverterTest#testCharacterS
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       End [4/7]: com.example.android.apis.os.MorseCodeConverterTest#testCharacterS
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       Start [5/7]: com.example.android.apis.view.Focus2AndroidTest#testGoingLeftFromRightButtonGoesToCent
er
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       End [5/7]: com.example.android.apis.view.Focus2AndroidTest#testGoingLeftFromRightButtonGoesToCenter

[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       Start [6/7]: com.example.android.apis.view.Focus2AndroidTest#testGoingRightFromLeftButtonJumpsOverC
enterToRight
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       End [6/7]: com.example.android.apis.view.Focus2AndroidTest#testGoingRightFromLeftButtonJumpsOverCen
terToRight
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       Start [7/7]: com.example.android.apis.view.Focus2AndroidTest#testPreconditions
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :       End [7/7]: com.example.android.apis.view.Focus2AndroidTest#testPreconditions
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :     Run ended: 212 ms
[INFO]   Tests run: 7,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 0
[INFO] emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk :   Report file written to C:\dev\jayway-maven-android-plugin-samples\apidemos-android-16\instrumen
tationtests\target\surefire-reports\TEST-emulator-5554_myDefaultAVD_unknown_google_sdk.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:05.798s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 15 22:26:49 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/350M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My maven version:

> Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
>   Maven home: C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin..
>   Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
>   Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

I tried several configuration changes in pom.xml without success. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is working correctly. The reason that the activity tests are not run is that they are "medium" tests and the test configuration is configured to only run "small" tests.

See https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/blob/master/apidemos-android-16/instrumentationtests/pom.xml

Specifically

```
 <configuration>
   <test>
      <testSize>small</testSize>
```

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/blob/master/apidemos-android-16/instrumentationtests/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/view/Focus2ActivityTest.java